# set LD_LIBRARY_PATH from Makefile

Tags: build-process

How do I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable from a Makefile?

I have some source code that links to a shared library that in turn links to a different shared library (more than 1). The Makefile for building the application only knows about the first shared library.

If I want to build this, I have to specify:
 `#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/the/shared/libs` (for bash)
and that works fine.

However, I would like to do this from the Makefile itself.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable within the makefile (e.g. because you have recursive Makefiles which all add to the variable), you can keep it bound to all calls to your compiler and linker.

Either you add it directly to all gcc and ld calls within your target rules, e.g.

```
my_target: my_target.o
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/library/path gcc -o my_target my_target.o
```

or you set the global make variables that define the compilers include the path, e.g.:

```
 CC=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/library/path gcc
 CPP=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/library/path gcc
 CXX=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/library/path gcc
```

I chose gcc as compiler but of course you can use any compiler you like.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, "export" is the correct directive to use. It is documented in detail [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion). This is the same mechanism as make itself uses to propagate variables to sub-makes. The drawback is that you cannot selectively pass down the variable to some commands and not to others.

There are two other options I can think of:

- Using `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` (specify as a target somewhere), causes all variables to be exported to the environment of sub-commands.
- Specify on the command line:

  ```
  foo:
      EXPORTEDVAR=somevalue gcc $< -o $@
  ```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, I had to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH as you did:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/the/shared/libs ; my_command
```

My friend showed me an alternative when LD_LIBRARY_PATH only applies to one command, notice no semicolon below.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/the/shared/libs my_command
```

This [article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c) explains more.

Answer (score 2):

I had tried adding:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/the/shared/libs
```

which apparently works fine.

I was getting errors because my /path/to/the/shared/libs was incorrect.

Would still be good to know what others do for this and/if there is a better way.

Comment: Are you sure this works? My understanding was that if you do that from the makefile, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` would be defined for this process and child processes, but not in the shell from which you ran `make`.

Answer (score 2):

Writing an equals sign (`=`) after the variable name overwrites the previous value of the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. It may be better to write a plus equals combination (`+=`). Then the new value will be added to the previous library path(s):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH += :/home/username/lib
```

Instead of

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /home/username/lib
```

Please note the colon symbol (`:`). As you know, it is a path separator and will ensure, that the new path added will work in unison with all the previous path(s) and the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a valid variable with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the top of the Makefile worked for me:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH := $(HOME)/lib
```

Pay attention not to add any extra spaces to the end of the line.  I wasted some time until I realized that was the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for a particular make , try this LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/the/shared/libs make.