# Missing Library in boost python compiled module

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am having trouble compiling and running a simple hello world example using Boost Python. In a previous install (at home) I was able to use sudo commands to install Boost in /usr/local/ but at my current location I don't have administrator access so I had to install it in another directory (./boost_1_55_0).

The code seems to compile but when I run an example python script I get the following error:

```
ImportError: libboost_python.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This shared object does exist in the ./boost_1_55_0/stage/lib directory. So in searching for my answer I tried adding the following to my Python script:

```
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']='./boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/'
```

But I get the same result. I have, in all cases, also tried absolute paths as well. In addition I looked in the following stackoverflow question:

[set LD_LIBRARY_PATH from Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787684/set-ld-library-path-from-makefile)

and tried to implement it but had no luck. I have attached the makefile, .cpp file and test script for any help someone can give. As an additional piece of information, I tried using distutils to compile but couldn't get that to work either. I have attached that python script as well.

Thanks for your help,

Nathan

---

Makefile:

```
# location of the Python header files

PYTHON_VERSION  = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE  = /usr/local/python/canopy_1.1.0/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/include/python2.7
PYTHON_LIB  = /usr/local/python/canopy_1.1.0/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.rh5-x86_64/lib

# location of the Boost Python include files and library

BOOST_INC = ./boost_1_55_0
BOOST_LIB = ./boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/

# compile mesh classes
TARGET = evoalg_gen

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(BOOST_LIB) g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -L$(PYTHON_LIB) -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -lboost_python -o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(BOOST_LIB) g++ -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).cpp
```

---

evoalg_gen.cpp:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

---

test_helloworld.py:

```
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']='./boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/'

#import EvoAlgs
import evoalg_gen
print hello_ext.greet()
```

---

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('EvoAlgs',
include_dirs = ['/raid1/nathanm/9502_Model/c++/boost_1_55_0'], ### Boost Directory
library_dirs = [''#, ### Boost Library
                #'/usr/local/python/epd-7.1-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/' ### Python Library
                ],
libraries = ['boost_python'],
sources = ['evoalg_gen.cpp'])

setup (name = 'EvoAlgs',
version = '0.1',
description = 'This is a collection of evolutionary algorithms',
ext_modules = [module1])
```

---

Additional info:

Running the command:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./boost_1_55_0/stage/lib python test_helloworld.py
```

gives the following error:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./boost_1_55_0/stage/lib: Command not found.
```

Following the suggestion by @kirbyfan64sos to add ,-rpath,./boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/ to my make file results in the following error when run:

```
ImportError: ./boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_python.so.1.55.0: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it must be set right before the program is actually run, not while it's running(does nothing) or while it's compiling(only sets the path for the compiler itself). For instance:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./boost_1_55_0/stage/lib python my_script.py
```

However, you can hardcode library paths into the library by using '-Wl,-rpath,'. So, in this case, when linking, you'd use '-Wl,-rpath,./
boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/ '.

Comment: Thank you for the info about LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I tried using both of your suggestions and I'm still not able to execute the test script. When I use your first suggestion I get an error saying that LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./boost_1_55_0/stage/lib: Command not found. When I add ,-rpath,./boost_... to my compile and try and run I get an error saying libboost_python.so.1.55.0: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @NateN: I'm not sure about the first error. The second error means that it's working, but there's some sort of issue involving unicode support. Try rebuilding Python while passing "--enable-unicode=ucs4" to the configure script.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that I can rebuild python since I don't have admin access on the machine. What I suppose I could do is build a custom install of python in my directory and use that instead. Your first answer definitely got rid of the initial error I had though so that has definitely helped me out!

Comment: @NateM: That should work just fine. Just remember to put the path to your new Python in user-config.jam and rebuild your library.