# ldd shows library not found for shared library dependency

Tags: gcc, ld

I am using some `-l` flags along with a `-L` flag to specify some shared libraries as dependencies. However when I look at the resulting `.so` with `ldd` it shows that the libraries I linked with were not found. Here is what I am compiling with:

```
gcc -std=c99 -fPIC -shared -o lib/libmylib.so src/mylib.o -lmydep -L/path/to/libmydep.so
```

what I have found to work is if I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the path before compiling it is able to find the library for `-ltest` but despite my attempts I haven't been able to successfully set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from my Makefile so this isn't a viable solution for me.

EDIT:

I have tried exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the following at the top of my Makefile:

```
... some var definitions ...
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /path/to/libmydep.so
... some more var definitions ...
export ... some vars ... LD_LIBRARY_PATH

... make targets start here ...
```

Comment: did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787684/set-ld-library-path-from-makefile?

Comment: @yflelion yes, maybe I am doing it wrong but I have tried this and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came across [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279397/ldd-does-not-find-path-how-to-add) question in which the answer provided by @schily worked for me.